# The meaning of "cocktail-plus"

Tags: meaning

Just encountered a compound noun "cocktail-plus" in an online article. Would like to confirm if it means a cocktail accompanied by some other drinks/ food in the reception?

The sentence is as follows:
"A dressy bag with a chain helps you hold crudités and a cocktail-plus, it lends a cool edge to evening wear, says stylist Cher Coulter."

Source: https://www.instyle.com/fashion/50-best-fashion-tips-all-time#3093620

Can "-plus' be added to any nouns to imply some more stuff of the same category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely a formatting error. An em dash was intended:

> A dressy bag with a chain helps you hold crudités and a cocktail—plus, it lends a cool edge to evening wear, says stylist Cher Coulter.

(This works because em dashes can be used to [separate a parenthetical](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html) from the rest of the sentence.)

Some other pages ([example](http://www.positiveimage.ie/style-tips/the-best-fashion-tips-of-all-time-a-selection-of/)) with that sentence have an em dash there.